# Can I connect a pendrive to samsung galaxy core?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb-on-the-go

I want to connect a pendrive to my device Samsung Galaxy Core with an OTG cable. Can you explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

USB-OTG is seemingly not supported according to the specs over at Gsmarena's [Galaxy Core](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_core_i8260-5419.php) page.

In contrast, see the [SGS4](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9500_galaxy_s4-5125.php), which offers USB on-the-go.

Comment: Can you give specific answer of my question

Comment: "Hardware no support OTG", what's unspecific about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your device does not support OTG.
Download the below app and check for yourself.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homesoft.otgtroubshooter

The app. detects and offers solutions to issues around USB Host and OTG cables. It's designed for the Nexus series, but should work with any Android device.

This app. does not offer support for USB devices. It simply detects whether they can be supported. It also detects certain Android bugs that may be affecting your system.

Comment: Care to summarize what that app is?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done.

USB Devices interact with your Android phone through a protocol known as USB On-The-Go (USB-OTG for short). This protocol has to be implemented in the software (kernel) level on supported hardware. Unfortunately, the Galaxy Core does NOT have this protocol available.